# Selecting specific points from array points

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I have Points array(Points[]). All points inside array have the same Y value.

For example 4 points:

```
(12 : 27)
(13 : 27)
(27 : 27)
(28 : 27)
```

I need to get **two** points from this array with the biggest difference on **X** axis.

In this example those points are:

**(12 : 27),(28 : 27)**

How can I get those points with help of Array extension, how can I write the Lambda expression?

```
 Point[] points = Array.Find(arrPoints,"Lambda expression");
```

OR

```
 Point[] points = arrPoints.Select("Lambda expression");
```

(I can use any extension method ont only Find() or Select())

Comment: your question is unclear (how is 12 bigger than 27?) but i think you want `arrayPoints.Min(x => x.X) and Max(x => x.X)`

Comment: "*I need to get two points from this array with the biggest difference on X axis.*" - Correct me if I'm wrong, but that will **always** be `max-min`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Array.Sort(points, (p1, p2) => p1.X.CompareTo(p2.X));
return new[] { points[0], points[points.Length-1] };
```

Note - this first performs an in-place sort on the array, meaning its order is changed permanently.

You can instead do:

```
var pDash = points.OrderBy(p => p.X).ToArray();
return new[] { pDash[0], pDash[pDash.Length-1] };
```

Personally I prefer the first because it doesn't involve twice the memory usage.

`Array.Sort` is not always preferable, however, because it's not a stable sort - however in this case it doesn't matter because the worst case would be that two identical points are swapped over - but they still represent the same point in space so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: You don't need to sort the entire data set to get the min and max values.

Comment: Yes, and doing so will both perform better, and clearly semantically show what it's trying to do.